# What's a word for a "cultural truth"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people say truth is not absolute but cultural and dependent on context. I think this is wrong. "Truth" should mean that which is the case. On the other hand I'd like to know a term for a proposition that, if agreed upon and treated as true, has value within a certain group or context although not in the absolute.

Comment: "That which is the case" is a very hard standard to enforce. Mostly we never know what the case is; then we have to improvise, by jumping to conclusions.

Comment: "That which is the case" really depends on what the meaning of the word "is" is.

Comment: @RegDwigнt also, 'the'. also... [The world is everything that is the case.
The world is the totality of facts](http://people.umass.edu/phil335-klement-2/tlp/tlp-ebook.pdf)

Comment: @Mitch you're right to bring up Wittgenstein, I'm getting the phrase "that which is the case" from the Tractatus.

Comment: @John Lawler, I think you're right that it's hard but enforcing it is a constant process not a simple yes or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about **(cultural) relativism**?

> A theory, especially in ethics or aesthetics, that **conceptions of truth** and moral values are not absolute but **are relative to** the persons or **groups holding them**.

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=relativism))

A proposition that is culturally relative can be referred to as a "cultural truth" (as in the title of your question), or a **"cultural truth claim"**.